# Keras EarlyStopping not working when change monitor to metric logged in customized callback

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm using tensorflow 2.6.2
and trying to change the default monitor metric to a metric calculated in my customized callback:

```
earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='my_metric', patience=20, verbose=1, mode='max', restore_best_weights=True)
```

And my callback looks like:

```
class my_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        ......
    
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs):
        
        #flatten label, pred_prod, weight
        for batch in self.validation:
            .........
        logs['my_metric'] = 'some_calculated_metric_over_valid_set'
```

And My final code looks like:

```
    callbacks_list = [my_callback(), earlystop]
    
    # train the model
    model_history = model.fit(
        train_dataset,
        epochs=5,
        verbose=1,
        shuffle=True,
        validation_data=validation_dataset,
        callbacks = callbacks_list
    )
```

But when training begins, earlystop callback still performs based on val_loss instead of 'my_metric'. my_callback() works perfectly fine in my code, so I wonder what causes this error?

I'm expecting earlystop callback decides when to stop training based on 'my_metric' instead of training loss.

Comment: I did some further experiments and found out the problem is from my custom callback but earlystopping: it's based on val_loss and I can't change it, even not if I use 'loss' as monitor metric